# Having issues using puppeteer on youtube

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm trying to write a scraper using puppeteer that logs each superchat(and super thanks eventually) posted in a youtube videos live stream.

Here is my current code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require("fs/promises")

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ykh6t3mec0")

    const superchats = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#purchase-amount-chip')).map(x => x.textContent)
    })
    await fs.writeFile("superchats.txt", superchats.join('\r\n'))
    await browser.close()
}

start()
```

This seems to work on other websites but youtube is very odd. Not sure what the issue is to be honest.

Comment: Usually, you need to wait for selectors to be ready, e.g. `page.waitForSelector("#purchase-amount-chip")`. Also, it's unusual to use `querySelectorAll` when there's only one element (`#` means "id", which must be unique per page), suggesting that you might be misunderstanding something about the DOM structure. That said, I don't see this selector anywhere and I'm not really sure what the super chats look like or what data you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah the #purchase-amount-chip was something left there after trying a bunch of different selectors to try and return anything from the youtube live chat lol. Each superchat has that ID attached to it. I tried page.waitForSelector and its timing out. 

I'm totally green to puppeteer. If these selectors dont appear until certain timestamps in the youtube video, is the assumption that I have to use the code to simulate the play button being clicked then use waitforselector to catch the superchat selector when it finally comes up?

Comment: `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({width: 1860, height: 1400});
    await page.goto("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ykh6t3mec0")
    
    await page.waitForSelector('span.yt-live-chat-ticker-paid-message-item-renderer').then(()=> console.log('found it'))

    await browser.close()
}

start()`

Comment: You can find the actual html element code im trying to target here -> https://shrib.com/#Amanda_koVYQ6

basically trying to get to that 4.99

Comment: @JoeG have you got this issue resolved?